# Multi-Line Regex: Find A where B is absent

Tags: ruby, regex

I have been looking through a lot on Regex lately and have seen a lot of answers involving the matching of one word, where a second word is absent.  I have seen a lot of [Regex Examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html) where I can have a Regex search for a given word (or any more complex regex in its place) and find where a word is missing.

It seems like the works very well on a line by line basis, but after including the multi-line mode it still doesn't seem to match properly.

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/yTJIQzDpst): Match an entire file string where the word `foo` is included, but the word `bar` is absent from the file.  What I have so far is `(?m)^(?=.*?(foo))((?!bar).)*$` which is based off the [example link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/completelines.html).  I have been testing with a Ruby Regex tester, but I think it is a open ended regex problem/question.  It seems to match smaller pieces, I would like to have it either match/not match on the entire string as one big chunk.

In the provided example above, matches are found on a line by line basis it seems.  What changes need to be made to the regex so it applies over the ENTIRE string?

**EDIT:** I know there are other more efficient ways to solve this problem that doesn't involve using a regex.  I am not looking for a solution to the problem using other means, I am asking from a *theoretical regex point of view*.  It has a multi-line mode (which looks to "work"), it has negative/positive searching which can be combined on a line by line basis, how come combining these two principals doesn't yield the expected result?

Comment: If you don't care about what the match returns but just wants to know *if* it matches, couldn't you use a simple string search function two times? (one for `foo`, and one for `bar`)?

Comment: The use case is on a very large set of files in Eclipse.  Using Eclipses built in search function you can search files using a Regex.  It would be tricky to search/compare those two sets of results, where a regex can be used to combine the query and find just the files pertaining to `foo` without reference to `bar`. ("search > file...").

It's really more theory wise, of what else is the regex missing to give it that entire file search, as opposed to the current result it gives.  I know there may be other ways to search, but it is aimed at the regex solution.

Comment: I am not horribly strong in regex, however I do know that $ means that you are stopping at the end of the line, no matter what. I also know that in Ruby \m at the end will wrap the regex. How to fix the regex beyond that, I am not sure

Comment: @JustinPihony the `(?m)` at the beginning does the same thing.  That is supposed to turn on 'multi line mode' which tells anchors like `^` and `$` to extend past new lines.  That is where this question is raised, how come that multi-line mode isn't working properly.  Compared to the example in the OP, [example](http://rubular.com/r/l0LE9uoOME) moving the `m` to the back returns the same results.  Removing that `m` does change the result, but still incorrect.

Comment: That’s not a solution you are likely looking for, but I was always meeting troubles using multiline regexps in all the implementation and finally came to the cheat with `gsub('\n', ).do_what_i_want.gsub(, '\n')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa is that just temporarily replacing all the newlines with other chars that regex is "dealing" with?  If so that seems like it could be VERY long/costly on a very large amount of files/lines.

Comment: @Walls yes, it is. But it should not be VERY costly until you are to proceed with vVERY large files.

Comment: @mudasobwa That would work, but I am curious more from the theory standpoint of regex what the solution is.  I know there are many ways to kludge a way to do this search, but I am curious how it can be done solely with a regex query (no replacements :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sawa's answer can be simplified, all that's needed is a positive lookahead, a negative lookahead, and since you're in multiline mode, `.*` takes care of the rest:

```
/(?=.*foo)(?!.*bar).*/m
```

Multiline means that `.` matches `\n` also, and matches are greedy. So the whole string will match without the need for anchors.

**Update**

@Sawa makes a good point for the `\A` being necessary but not the `\Z`.
Actually, looking at it again, the positive lookahead seems unnecessary:

```
/\A(?!.*bar).*foo.*/m
```

Comment: This does not work. It will incorrectly match (a part of) `"bar foo"`. That is why my regex has anchors to ensure the negative lookahead affects the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

A regex that matches an entire string that does not include `foo` is:

```
/\A(?!.*foo.*).*\z/m
```

and a regex that matches from the beginning of an entire string that includes `bar` is:

```
/\A.*bar/m
```

Since you want to satisfy both of these, take a conjunction of these by putting one of them in a lookahead:

```
/\A(?=.*bar)(?!.*foo.*).*\z/m
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.  It seems when I was using multi-line mode, it is better to use `\A` and `\z` to handle starting/ending the string respectively.  The error was using `^` and `$`.  Thanks!  NOTE: The example has the answer stuff flipped, but it works when corrected to find foo, don't find bar.